# multiple async-await in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, async-await, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

obj in promoType = [list of string]
its more like 10 firebase queries are running here, looking in 10 particular set of nodes and going down further.

what i'm not sure, whether i require to put on async / await on each of the queries, but all i want is 10 of these queries to run and then result me in whether a couponKey is empty or not. All i want to do is to display whether a coupon entered was correct or not.

further, in changeUserType(couponKey, couponFoundAtKey), some database write operations occur.

```
fun checkPromo(promoCodeET: String) = async(UI) {
    try {
        val database = PersistentFirebaseUtil.getDatabase().reference
        val job = async(CommonPool) {

            for (obj in promoType) {
                val query = database.child("promos").child(obj).orderByChild("promoCode").equalTo(promoCodeET)

                query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object :
                        ValueEventListener {
                    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            couponKey = dataSnapshot.key.toString()
                            couponFoundAtKey = dataSnapshot.children.first().key.toString()
                            if (couponKey.isNotEmpty())
                                changeUserType(couponKey, couponFoundAtKey)
                            flag = true
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                        // Failed to read value
                    }
                })
                if (flag) break
            }
        }
        job.await()            

    }
    catch (e: Exception) {
    }
    finally {
        if (couponKey.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(this@Coupon, "Invalid coupon", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
        flag = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things I find wrong with your code:

1. You have an outer `async(UI)` which doesn't make sense
2. Your inner `async(CommonPool)` doesn't make sense either, because your database call is already async
3. You use the antipattern where you immediately `await` after `async`, making it not really "async" (but see above, the whole thing is async with or without this)
4. Your fetching function has a side-effect of changing the user type
5. To transfer the results to the caller, you again use side-effects instead of the return value

Your code should be much simpler. You should declare a `suspend fun` whose return value is the pair `(couponKey, coupon)`:

```
suspend fun fetchPromo(promoType: String, promoCodeET: String): Pair<String, String>? =
    suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
        val database = PersistentFirebaseUtil.getDatabase().reference
        val query = database.child("promos").child(promoType)
                .orderByChild("promoCode").equalTo(promoCodeET)
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                cont.resume(
                    dataSnapshot
                        .takeIf { it.exists() }
                        ?.let { snapshot ->
                            snapshot.key.toString()
                                .takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }
                                ?.let { key ->
                                    Pair(key, snapshot.children.first().key.toString())
                                }
                        }
                )
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError?) {
                if (error != null) {
                    cont.resumeWithException(MyException(error))
                } else {
                    cont.cancel()
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

To call this function, use a `launch(UI)` at the call site. Change the user type once you get a non-null value:

```
launch(UI) {
    var found = false
    for (type in promoType) {
        val (couponKey, coupon) = fetchPromo(type, "promo-code-et") ?: continue
        found = true
        withContext(CommonPool) {
            changeUserType(couponKey, coupon)
        }
        break
    }
    if (!found) {
        Toast.makeText(this@Coupon, "Invalid coupon", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

You say that `changeUserType` performs some database operations, so I wrapped them in a `withContext(CommonPool)`.

Note also that I extracted the loop over promo types outside the function. This will result in queries being performed sequentially, but you can just write different calling code to achieve parallel lookup:

```
var numDone = 0
var found = false
promoType.forEach { type ->
    launch(UI) {
        fetchPromo(type, "promo-code-et")
            .also { numDone++ }
            ?.also { (couponKey, coupon) ->
                found = true
                launch(CommonPool) {
                    changeUserType(couponKey, coupon)
                }
            }
            ?: if (numDone == promoType.size && !found) {
                Toast.makeText(this@Coupon, "Invalid coupon", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is like simplicity-heaven in your answer! 
can you please refer to me more on where could i read on launch(UI)
& .also , .takeIf ?

Comment: These are some great resources for coroutines: [kotlin-coroutines-informal](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-coroutines/blob/master/kotlin-coroutines-informal.md) [coroutines-by-example](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md) [coroutines-README](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-coroutines) [coroutines-guide-ui](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/ui/coroutines-guide-ui.md)

Comment: `.also` and `.takeIf` are extension functions available for any type, including `null`. They are a part of the standard library and an essential aspect of idiomatic Kotlin code. I recommend you to study all these standard extension functions and try to use them everywhere, that way you'll learn when they provide value.